# Why can't I have a subreport with horizontal column print order in the summary band?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a 2-column subreport containing a title band and a detail band.

This subreport is placed inside the summary band of the master report.

The subreport contains a table in the detail band. I want the contents of the table to be printed horizontally, so I set the columns print order of the subreport to `Horizontal`.

Now I'm getting the following exception:

```
15:45:23,238 [ptc subreports #1] ERROR JRFillSubreport - Fill 2: exception net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Subreport overflowed on a band that does not support overflow.
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.addPage(JRVerticalFiller.java:1845)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillPageBreak(JRVerticalFiller.java:1939)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBreak(JRVerticalFiller.java:1968)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:754)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportContent(JRVerticalFiller.java:308)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:155)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:909)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:841)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.fillSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:660)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRSubreportRunnable.run(JRSubreportRunnable.java:59)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.AbstractThreadSubreportRunner.run(AbstractThreadSubreportRunner.java:203)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
15:45:23,240 [ptc subreports #1] DEBUG AbstractThreadSubreportRunner - Fill 2: notifying of completion
15:45:23,240 [main] DEBUG AbstractThreadSubreportRunner - Fill 2: notified of fill result
15:45:23,240 [main] ERROR JRFillSubreport - Fill 1: exception net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Subreport overflowed on a band that does not support overflow.
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.addPage(JRVerticalFiller.java:1845)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillPageBreak(JRVerticalFiller.java:1939)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBreak(JRVerticalFiller.java:1968)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:754)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportContent(JRVerticalFiller.java:308)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:155)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:909)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:841)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.fillSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:660)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRSubreportRunnable.run(JRSubreportRunnable.java:59)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.AbstractThreadSubreportRunner.run(AbstractThreadSubreportRunner.java:203)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

If I set the column print order to `Vertical`, the problem goes away.

Comment: Weird, the detail band is the one that does not support vertical print order. Are you setting both the summary and the detail to `Vertical` by any chance?.

Comment: I don't see how I can set the print order of a particular band, I can only set it for the whole report. My subreport is set to `Horizontal` and the master report was set to `Vertical` and `Horizontal`. Neither worked.